# Performance Issues with Web App

Tags: web-hosting, performance, webserver, web-applications

I'm currently preparing the release of an online tool: example.net/configurator

Unfortunately, I've got massive performance issues. I'm currently hosting at A2 Hosting which I actually thought to be one of the fastest webhosters.
Does anyone of you know where to get an even faster webserver? A small loading time and a small communication time with the webserver is very important for this project.

Comment: Google Cloud is among the fastest since they have the biggest pipes on the planet.

Comment: @SimonHayter *Google Cloud is among the fastest since they have the biggest pipes on the planet.* this is **very** subjective and nothing is clear cut in all cases just like that. The question is far too vague to be able to get useful replies, there are many issues to take into account, like the expected geographic locations of clients.

Comment: The OP does not tell us what the specific performance issue is. I have set up global websites for very specific purposes where performance was a paramount consideration. This should not be a problem generally. As well, the OP does not tell us what the expectation is. It may be the expectation is unrealistic. There may be help for the OP if there were some details. Cheers!!

Comment: Which details do you need? Well, we'll get clients from all over the world and the latency has to be very low as our online tool will be highly interactive. It shows a WebGL animation.